# extracting instruments for mendelian randomization analysis

Tags: r, statistics, bioinformatics, gwas

I am looking at extracting genetic variants associated with physical activity (to be used as exposure) from gwas id  ebi-a-GCST006097. The  gwas has nsnp = 11808007

```r
library(TwoSampleMR)
library(ieugwasr)

gwasinfo ("ebi-a-GCST006097")
```

However, when I extract this, I end up with an nsnp = 19

```r
ao <- available_outcomes()
PA.data <- extract_instruments(outcomes = 'ebi-a-GCST006097')
```

This means that I am unable to carry out harmonization as none of this 19 snps are in my outcome data (which has 3 snps). I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. I have looked at all relevant tutorial I can see online including one from mrcieu.github.io/TwoSampleMR. Any assistance will be helpful.

Comment: If you do not quickly get an answer you need here, on Stack Overflow, try posting the question on [Bioinformatics Stack Exchange](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/) or [Biostars](https://www.biostars.org/), both of which deal with bioinformatics.

Comment: Good idea. Thanks.